# Protobuf on Android: Error Duplicate classes defined in protoc file when compile

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I want to write a Grpc client on Android. I follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/basic/android.md)

Here is my outer `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0"

    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.3.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Here is my inner file `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'

    // You need to build grpc-java to obtain these libraries below.
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.3.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.3.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.3.0' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}
```

When I tried to build project, I always meet errors:

```
Error:(14, 15) error: duplicate class: io.grpc.routeguideexample.Feature
Error:(13, 15) error: duplicate class: io.grpc.routeguideexample.FeatureDatabase
// ...
```

With `Feature` ... is class that I have defined in protoc file. Please help me figure out what wrong in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined a Java class `io.grpc.routeguideexample.Feature` in your code, this will conflict with the generated class name from the `route_guide.proto` file, causing the error you described. You can either change the name or package of your own `Feature` and `FeatureDatabase` class, or change the `route_guide.proto` to use a different Java package name. In general, you can look for a directory like `build/generated/source/proto/.../javalite/io/grpc/routeguideexample/` to see the actual generated code from your proto files.